# mysqldump dump completed but data not loaded

Tags: mysql

Im trying to dump the a sql file and get the below results..It says "dump completed" but the database.

```
ps@Pds-MacBook-Pro robe-code $ mysqldump -u ninja -p robe<shgp_prod_latest.mysql 
Enter password: 
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.11, for osx10.9 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: Krobe
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.11

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-01-26 17:51:21
```

Comment: `mysqldump` is for exporting to a file, not importing from a file.

Comment: thanks Barmar..its a silly mistake

Answer (score 3):

Once I had same problem, when I was trying to import Database into mariaDb.
There are TWO reasons for this output:

***One:***
Problem here with your command is, **mysqldump** is used export database not import.
use **mysql** instead.

also we use ***<*** to import and ***>*** to export.

***TWO:***
it also shows same output if **.sql** size is 0byte.

Answer (score 0):

The correct output redirection operator would be > and not <